# SQLAlchemy Many-To-Many performance

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a database relationship with a Many-To-Many association but the association table itself contains a lot of attributes that need to be accessed, so I made three classes:

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    attempts = relationship("UserAttempt", backref="user", lazy="subquery")

class Challenge(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    attempts = relationship("UserAttempt", backref="challenge", lazy='subquery')

class UserAttempt(Base):
    challenge_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('challenge.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
```

This is a simplified case, of course, where I left out the other attributes that I need to access. The purpose here is, that each `User` can attempt any number of `Challenge`s, hence the `UserAttempt` table which described one particular user working one challenge.

The problem now: When I query for all Users and then look at each attempt, I am perfectly fine. But when I look at the challenge for this attempt, it explodes in numerous subqueries. Of course, this is bad for performance.

What I actually want from SQLAlchemy is to pull all (or all relevant) Challenges *at once* and then associate it with the relevant attempts. It is not a big deal if all challenges are pulled or only does which have an actual association later, as this the number of challenges is only between 100-500.

My solution right now is actually not very elegant: I pull all relevant attempts, challenges and users seperately and then associate by hand: Loop through all attempts and assign add to the challenge & user, then add the challenge & user to the attempt as well. That seems to me like a brutal solution that should not be necessary.

However, every approach (e.g. varying "lazy" parameters, altered queries, etc.) have led to queries from hundreds to thousands. I have also tried to write plain `SQL` queries that would yield my desired results and have come up with something along the lines of `SELECT * FROM challenge WHERE id IN (SELECT challenge_id FROM attempts)` and that worked well, but I cannot get it translated to `SQLAlchemy`

Thank you very much in advance for any guidance you may have to offer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What I actually want from SQLAlchemy is to pull all (or all relevant) Challenges at once and then associate it with the relevant attempts. It is not a big deal if all challenges are pulled or only does which have an actual association later,

You first want to take off that "lazy='subquery'" directive from relationship() first; fixing relationships to always load everything is why you're getting the explosion of queries.  Specifically here, you're getting that Challenge->attempts eagerload exactly for each lazyload of UserAttempt->Challenge so you've sort of designed the worst possible loading combination here :).

With that fixed, there's two approaches.

One is to keep in mind that many-to-one association in the usual case is fetched from the Session in memory first by primary key, and if present, no SQL is emitted.  So I think you could get exactly the effect it seems like you're describing using a technique I use often:

```
all_challenges = session.query(Challenge).all()

for user in some_users:    # however you got these
    for attempt in user.attempts:   # however you got these
        do_something_with(attempt.challenge)  # no SQL will be emitted
```

If you wanted to use the above approach with exactly the "Select * from challenge where id in (select challenge_id from attempt)":

```
all_challenges = session.query(Challenge).\
                  filter(Challenge.id.in_(session.query(UserAttempt.challenge_id))).all()
```

though this is likely more efficient as a JOIN:

```
all_challenges = session.query(Challenge).\
                  join(Challenge.attempts).all()
```

or DISTINCT, I guess the join would return the same challenge.id as it appears in UserAttempt:

```
all_challenges = session.query(Challenge).distinct().\
                  join(Challenge.attempts).all()
```

The other way is to use eager loading more specifically.    you can query for a bunch of users/attempts/challenges within one query that will emit three SELECT statements:

```
users = session.query(User).\
              options(subqueryload_all(User.attempts, UserAttempt.challenge)).all()
```

or because UserAttempt->Challenge is many-to-one, a join might be better:

```
users = session.query(User).\
                  options(subqueryload(User.attempts), joinedload(UserAttempt.challenge)).all()
```

just from UserAttempt:

```
attempts = session.query(UserAttempt).\
                  options(joinedload(UserAttempt.challenge)).all()
```